# Sometimes Image overflows in Lightbox 2

Tags: lightbox2

I'm just wondering why sometimes my image inside the `lightbox` plugin overflows and sometimes it doesn't?

Help me please, I tried to edit the **CSS** but no luck :(

[image: Example of overflow]

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to remove the padding on the container:

```
.lb-container {
    padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

This solution may not be optimal because it gets rid of the white borders but it will yield a decent result.